# How to account for bad data in primary key for SQL

Tags: sql

I am not actually using SQL, it's a proprietary language that's based on it, but the format is similar. Right now we are having issues with how data is stored on the table, because of user input error and how the system is built. There is a priority key that can be misnumbered, and there isn't a row number that I can go based off of. The data in the tables is like this:

```
1.  Name 1
2.  Name 2
3.  Name 3
5.  Name 4
6.  Name 5
```

As an example. It hasn't happened yet, but there is the ability to have numerous mis-keys, so I am trying to fix all edge cases in the code before I try to remedy this. Right now, the code is setting an identifier based on the primary key and the size, and I'm trying to write code to account for mis numbered primary keys.

Pseudo code:

```
count = size(table)

for (x = 1 to count){
     select into:
        from table y
     where x = primarykey
     set variable = name
}
```

I've been trying to think of ways to account for this mis-numbering, but whatever I'm trying isn't also catching edge cases of skipping two numbers. The issue is the loop stops at #5, instead of #6, because the size of the table is five items but the last number is actually 6.

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're trying to do. Are you just trying to make sure you iterate over every single row?

Comment: I think you should tell us what your actual tool/language is, because your problem may be further from SQL than you think, at least from the point of view of getting an answer here.

Comment: The primary key is a unique identifier of the row. It doesn't need to (shouldn't) be visible to the end user. Why do you care what value it has? As long as it is **unique** you are good. Aren't you?

Comment: To expand on @TheImpaler's comment, one would expect the data itself to somehow establish priority, rather than an id. Consider the robustness of relying on an id to establish priority: in a distributed or asynchronous environment, for example, is that the most reliable way to ensure A and B are in the right order? So, the question is: what feature(s) of a record can be used to set that priority (timestamp, etc), then generate your priority numbers from a sort on those fields.